# Looking for suggestion on lstm models

Tags: python, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I am quite new to machine learning and RNN. 
I have a small problem as follows: the problem has 4 independent input variables (says (x1, x2, x_3, x_4)) and a vector output (says y_out = 100x1 elements). I want to built a LSTM model to predict the new y_out for any input set (x_1new, x_2new, x_3new, x_4new). 
Let say, I build a sample dataset = 50000 lines, each line consists of [x_1i, x_2i, x_3i, x_4i, y_outi]. So my dataset has the dimension of 50000x(4+100).

I don't know how to configure my LSTM model. Any suggestion would be appreciated.

I have already tried the NN model such as Backpropagation with very worst prediction results.

Thank you

Comment: Just to be sure... why are you using LSTM and not something else?

Comment: I am following an article and want to verify their results. They used LSTM with a similar problem.

Comment: Can you share the article to get a better idea of what you want to do?

Comment: Please search for this article: Neural network representation of a phase-ﬁeld model for brittle fracture (Arnd Koeppe, Franz Bamer, Carlos Alberto Hernandez Padilla, and Bernd Markert)